# Background fetch stopped working on ios 13 and newer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-fetch

If a method is Deprecated, does this mean it will not work in updated systems?

I was using setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval for background fetch and I believe it stopped working for ios 13 and newer versions.

Do you think it is because it is deprecated or a bug?

When I use Simulate Background Fetch it works fine, but it does not fetch when I really use the app.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

      let successCallback: (_ data: Double) -> Void = { (data) in
        
        if data == nil {
          // No new data
          completionHandler(.noData)
        } else {
          // There is a new data set
          self.bodyMassObserverQueryTriggered() // count todays steps and updates database
          completionHandler(.newData)
            
        }
      }
      
        getSteps(completion: successCallback) // count todays steps and updates database
    }
```

and I have the following lines in applicationdidfinishwithoptions:

```
UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(5*60)
```

Do I need anything else?

**EDIT:** One thing i found is i needed to remove BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers from Info.plist according to apple docs:

*Adding a BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers key to the Info.plist disables application(*:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:) and setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(*:) in iOS 13 and later.*